# Ruby On Rails Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Is there a way for me to call ruby on rails functions from within javascript?
For instance I have a partial => _micropost_form.html.erb and I want it to appear in a separate div when a button is clicked. I figured the best way to do that would be to use javascript. Currently I have:

```
document.getElementById("micropost").innerHTML=
```

So I'm pretty lost. I feel like this should be a pretty simple problem to work out though. Thanks!

EDIT:

So I have a link in my _header file:

```
<li>Add Content</li>
```

As well as a div:

```
<div id="popout"></div>
```

In my content controller I have a method:

```
def add_content
@content = Content.new
respond_to do |format|
format.html
format.js
end
```

As well as the file (located in views/contents) add_content.js.erb (_content_form is an html.erb file located in shared)

```
$('#popout').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript render
            (:file => 'shared/_content_form') %>");
```

I know the call I'm supposed to make in `<li>Add Content</li>` involves `link_to` however, I have yet to be able to get it to work correctly. The output to the console usually looks like a page refresh. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you had a look at these? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=call+ruby+on+rails+function+from+javascript

Comment: I have actually. They aren't helpful at all.

Comment: They at least tell you that you have to use Ajax to retrieve the data... and then you might find questions like these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ruby+on+rails+load+partial+with+ajax. I cannot say whether there are good answers (I don't work with RoR), but the questions seem all to go in the same direction as yours.

Comment: They're not real helpful. I understand what you're trying to do, but I've searched the web as well as here. I don't need you to show me the search results for the same queries I had just finished doing.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you'd tell us what you already know...

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I should have been more clear with what I knew. I'll keep that in mind in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer by [ismaelga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634513/ismaelga), I would like to add that if you have static HTML content in `_micropost_form.html.erb` then there's no reason why that should be a `erb` file or a `partial`.  Having that content within a `hidden div` and then toggling that based on the button click would be a good solution.

If, however, you have dynamic content in that file then your best bet is to use `AJAX`.  Some of the links provided by [Felix Cling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) in the comments are a good starting point.  I find myself using the following line of code in the `.js.erb` file quite a bit though to achieve what you want to:

```
$('#micropost').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'micropost_form.html.erb') %>");
```

Or, you could use the jquery [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

Comment: The line of code you provided is exactly what I was looking for. However, I'm having trouble getting it working. In the javascript function I wrote earlier I am instead just calling what you had above.  Is that all you have to do or is there some intricacy there that I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: This line is executed `server-side` and not `client-side` - so you can't include it straight into a `javascript` file.
In the appropriate controller, you need to have a `respond_to` block with a `format.js` (which is normally reached through a `AJAX` call or having a `.js` extension on the webpage instead of `.html`.).  The view that is then rendered is the appropriate `<view_name>.js.erb`.  

Is this what you're doing?

Comment: No, not at all. I'll look into that and see what I can figure out. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've got the general idea and have it working with a simple example. However, I'm struggling to get it working with a more complicated example. I've edited the initial question above to reflect my current situation.

Answer (score 0):

make it appear in an iframe:

```
function appear_it() {
   document.getElementById("micropost").innerHTML = "<iframe id="micropostframe" src="bla/whatever.html"></iframe>";
}
```

Then you can style it with css.

Have a button or a link with the attribute onclick="appear_it();return false".

Comment: @ismaelga- WUT YOU SAY!? Iframes is wunderful creature that love people. Gmail used like 20 iFrames

Comment: google it: "iframes evil". Actually they are not evil, just some people use it in cases that it wasn't suppose to. What I mean is iframes should be use when you need to show some content that DOES NOT belong to your application, so there is no sharing data, styling, no nothing. Facebook is a good example, they use it for foreign applications to show up inside their page, and maybe google uses it for similar purposes. But everyone has their thoughts and ways of doing things, like no one said you MUST do the page styling on a external css file, but it actually is a good thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you are trying to achieve, rendering that "div" on the request as hidden and then the link trigger a js function to show it.

This should be a good solution unless that "link" brings some conditionals for what you want to render, for example if there is only one thing to display or else if you have many links to show at same div different content depending on the link you click. If the second case is the one you are trying to solve, you should really check ajax calls. Btw JQuery is your friend for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I think toggle will work for me as of now, but I will need to study both AJAX and jQuery a little more heavily. Thanks!